# How to create API POST request using axios for upload local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a use case to upload local file using axios but i have a problem how to passing file in body of axios

here the curl is successfully hit api

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.test.com/uploadReceipt' \
--header 'tokenId: TOKENID' \
--header 'transactionId: 12345' \
--header 'Origin: ORIGIN_HOST' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/pdf' \
--data-binary '@/home/files/receipts/receipt12345.pdf'
```

then i convert to axios like this

```
async function uploadPdf(transaction) {
    try {
        const transactionid = transaction.id;
        const receipts = fs.createReadStream("/home/files/receipts/" + transaction.fileName);
        const { data } = await axios({
            baseURL: BASE_URL,
            method: 'post',
            url: API_URL,
            headers: {
                'tokenid': TOKEN,
                'Origin': HEADER_ORIGIN,
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                'transactionId': transactionid 
            },
            data: receipts
        });
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);  
    }
}
```

But when i run axios keep getting bad request. Then i tried to convert read stream to binary

```
receipts.setEncoding('binary')
```

but not solving the issue.

Have anyone ever create axios request by passing file in request body ?
Can you explain the right way to do it ?

Comment: `--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` doesn't make sense. The body is a PDF not URL encoded form data.

Comment: try reading this: https://maximorlov.com/send-a-file-with-axios-in-nodejs/

Comment: i have follow that tutorial but not working

Comment: i have change content type to `application/pdf` but not working too

Comment: Try to achieve same from postman then refer the code generated by it.

Comment: Postman generated axios is only `var data = "<file content>"` then pass it to axios body. I am dont know how `<file content>` should look like

Comment: Did you solve this.? Looking to solve same problem here.

Comment: I solve this by changing `fs.createReadStream` to `fs.readFileSync`